# Is it possible to use ZXing with codename one?

Tags: lwuit, zxing, codenameone

I need to know whether Codename One supports [zxing.](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) If not, Is there any other way to scan the QR code with Codename One? I need to use this on both android and iPhone. Is it possible with Codename One?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We intend to add support for that relatively soon. If you have specific requirements please open an issue/RFE, we tend to promote RFE's from community members faster.

Comment: Thanks shai. I posted my [requirement here.](http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/detail?id=170)

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FDemos%2FZXing) is a working example how to use [zxing](/questions/tagged/zxing) within [codenameone](/questions/tagged/codenameone) via native calls.

there's also a [codenameone](/questions/tagged/codenameone) class for scanning barcodes ([javadoc](https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/codescan/CodeScanner.html)). You could find a usage example [here](http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/Demos/BarCodeScanner/).